# Lists compared in a if function

Tags: python-3.8

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZGO5.png)

```
>>> if LIST[2] == "a" or "A":
    print("Yes")

Yes

>>> LIST[2]
'l'
```

Can someone please explain this?

I'm trying to compare items in a list to initiate a function. But Python is telling me that `"l" == "a" or "A"`

Is it something to do with the or in the code.

Comment: I think you need if LIST[2] == 'a' or LIST[2] == 'A':

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your help @Kensus . Yes I have made the change as sugested and my program works perfectly. Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that it has something to do with the `or`. I assume you want to see if LIST[2] is equal to either "a" or "A". The correct way to do this is 
`if LIST[2] == "a" or LIST[2] == "A"` or `if LIST[2] in "aA"`

So here's whats actually happening in your code:

`if LIST[2] == "a" or "A":` is the same as `if (LIST[2] == "a") or "A"`. `(LIST[2] == "a")` is false. But `or` with strings is still a valid operation! `x or "A"` will evaluate to `x` if `x` is true or `"A"` if `x` is false. Since `(LIST[2] == "a")` is false, the `or` gives `"A"` resulting in `if "A":`. Python considers all non-empty strings to be true, and the empty string `""` to be false. So, `"A"` is considered true, and the statement inside the `if` is executed.